# Why does my Ellipse mask and FastGaussian nodes have no effect on my image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, image, effects

I was following a video tutorial and I want to achieve the same effect in the *Fast_Gaussian*, I want that like sort of dark colors that form like a circle ( Vignette ), Also when I change the color or the tone the whole image just changes the color , or turns darker/lighter

my scene :
[image]

Desired result :
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a RGB input to the mask.

[image]

Also, to control the darkness of the vignette, use a Bright/Contrast node to the mix.